# Getting custom field entries from WordPress users

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I have a template where I show users like:

```
<?php
    $values = get_field('personen_intern');
    if($values)
{
    echo '<ul>';             
    foreach($values as $value)      
    {
        echo '<li>' . $value['display_name'] . '</li>';
    }
    echo '</ul>';
} ?>
```

Getting normal values like "display name" is no problem here but how to get custom field entries from the user pages (like "phone", "birthdate" etc.)?  I am using "advanced custom fields" plugin to build the custom fields.

Also I tried a user query like this:

```
<?php
$args = array(  
'relation' => 'AND',
    array(
        'key'     => 'personen_intern',
        'value' => '"'.$user_id.'"',
        'compare' => '='
    )
);
?>
```

But this shows me all users. I want to query only the users added to the page with the `user-relationship` field.

I think i have to check if the user IDs that i get on the page are similar to user IDs in a user_query and than drop the ones that are not in.

Comment: Check post meta and post custom values and see if the values are stored there. Something like `print_r(get_post_custom());` will output the post custom values on your page, and you can see what values are present, and what aren't.

Comment: This doesn't give me the meta entrys from the users only from the page the users are listed on. When i do someting like "var_dump( $user->telefon );" ("telefon" is a user custom field) i get nothing.

Comment: And what is `$user` variable?

Comment: "$user" is a given wordpress variable to get user information: https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_User. I somehow have to hook into the user meta info but i don't know how.

Comment: Try with [WP_User_Query](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_User_Query)

Comment: Thanks, i tried this first with no results (edited my post).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88837/discussion-between-henning-fischer-and-dingo-d).

Answer (score 0):

Try this, replace `field_name` with the field name and `user_1` with `user_` plus the user id. So a user with an id of 23 would be `user_23`.

```
 <?php the_field('field_name', 'user_1'); ?>
```

You could use it within a user loop like this:

```
$user_query = new WP_User_Query() );

    $user_array = array();

        // User Loop
        if ( ! empty( $user_query->results ) ) {
            foreach ( $user_query->results as $user ) {

                $id = $user->ID;
                $field = get_field('field_name', 'user_'.$id );

                if ( $field ) { echo '<li>' . $field . '</li>'}

            }
        }
```

This would query all users but only display the ones where the field_name is set.

Comment: I want to filter the users with the query. I don't get nothing with your code but if it would work i had just one specific user. But what i want to do is getting users that i added to the page with a user relationship field.

Comment: The users have no custom fields, the users ARE the custom fields (user relationship custom field) that are added to the page and i want to show only the ones that are added to the page.

Answer (score 0):

Got it.

```
<?php
    $ids = get_field('personen_intern', false, false);

    $args = array(          
        'include' => $ids,
    );
?>

… loop content here
```

First get the IDs of the persons from the custom fields and after this just include them in the query.